# How do I make tkinter text rotate with a spinning wheel?

Tags: python, tkinter, rotation, tkinter-canvas

This is my first time using stack overflow, so I apologize if formatting is wrong

I'm trying to make this function do 2 things. First, I'm drawing a wheel with an amount of fields equal to the amount of descriptions given, with field having a different hue of a given color. Then, the text for each option is given via the array of strings, and this text should be put inside each of the fields on the wheel. I have figured out where to place the text, but I can't seem to get the rotation down.

```
    def drawWheel(self):
        """
        Draws the GUI wheel with a random selection of colors. Uses amount of string objects as amount of fields
        """
        anglePerSection = 360 / self.sections
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = 30, 30, 570, 570
        radius = 250
        centerX, centerY = 300, 300
        self.canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="white")

        for i, description in enumerate(self.descriptions):
            startAngle = anglePerSection * i + self.angle
            txtStartAngle = anglePerSection * i - self.angle
            self.canvas.create_arc(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                                   start=startAngle,
                                   extent=anglePerSection,
                                   fill=self.getColorBrightness(self.color, i),
                                   outline="black")
            midpointAngle = (txtStartAngle + (anglePerSection / 2)) % 360
            angle_rad = np.radians(midpointAngle)
            textX = centerX + radius * np.cos(angle_rad)
            textY = centerY + radius * np.sin(angle_rad)
            self.canvas.create_text(textX, textY, text=description, font=("Arial", 14), fill="white", angle=anglePerSection * i + startAngle)

        self.canvas.create_oval(centerX - 85, centerY - 85, centerX + 85, centerY + 85, fill="white")
```

I'm placing the text using the `self.canvas.create_text(textX, textY, text=description, font=("Arial", 14), fill="white", angle=midpointAngle-90 % 360)` where the angle param should calculate the needed rotation of the text. I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct rotation however.

I've tried a few different calculations, mainly using `anglePerSection * i + startAngle` with no luck. The good news is, the text rotation angle stays consistent with this calculation, so I'm thinking I just need to add some constant value to orient all the numbers correctly. They should of course be oriented so the text fills the field from the edge to the center.

Edit: Minimum reproducable example

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    sections = 21
    numberList = [str(i) for i in range(1, sections + 1)]
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    anglePerSection = 360 / sections
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = 30, 30, 570, 570
    radius = 250
    centerX, centerY = 300, 300
    canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="white")
    for i, number in enumerate(numberList):
        startAngle = anglePerSection * i
        canvas.create_arc(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                          start=startAngle,
                          extent=anglePerSection,
                          fill="white",
                          outline="black")
        midpointAngle = (startAngle + anglePerSection / 2) % 360
        angle_rad = np.radians(midpointAngle)
        textX = centerX + radius * np.cos(angle_rad)
        textY = centerY + radius * np.sin(angle_rad)
        canvas.create_text(textX, textY, text=number, font=("Arial", 14), fill="black", angle=anglePerSection * i + startAngle)

    root.mainloop()
```

This code produces a circle with numbered fields. The closest number to the orientation I'm looking for is 11. Another thing to add here, I am also having trouble drawing the bottom half of the numbers, but I will concern myself with this later

Comment: Can you share whole code so it will be possible to run it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to share code, other than to send a link to the github repo I'm using for it https://github.com/AncientCarbon/DNDWheelOfDestiny

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. We don't need *all* of your code, just enough to be able to run an example and reproduce the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have calculated `textY` wrong, it should be:

```py
textY = centerY - radius * np.sin(angle_rad)
```

because y-coordinate of a canvas goes from top to bottom.

Also the value of `midpointAngle` is what you want on the `angle` option of the text item:

```py
canvas.create_text(textX, textY, text=number, font=("Arial", 14),
                   fill="black", angle=midpointAngle)
```

Output:

[image]

Or `angle=midpointAngle-90`:

[image]